# Aria completed state?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

When programming/designing for accessibility, is there a proper method for conveying that a particular item is "completed"?

Currently building some accessible e-learning. In a particular activity there are a number of buttons that must be pressed, where activating each button reveals further information in a separate panel. In this particular example, I am using a tablist.

Once all tabs have been visited, the user can move forward to the next activity.

Would changing the aria-label's to something like "Tab 1 - complete" or "Tab 1 - not complete" suffice for indicating their state?

### **Update 1**

For clarification, in this particular example I'm using a tablist, using the methodology from [Inclusive Components - Tabbed Interfaces](https://inclusive-components.design/tabbed-interfaces/). The unordered list is required to have a `role="tablist"`, so I can't use the `role="progressbar"`.
ie:

```
<ul role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation"> <a role="tab" href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 1</a> </li>
  <li role="presentation"> <a role="tab" href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell assistive technologies such as screen readers that an element shows progress by giving it [`role="progressbar"`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#progressbar). Then, you can set up minimum and maximum values with `aria-valuemin` and `aria-valuemax`, respectively, and display the current value with `aria-valuenow`. By default, screen readers speak `aria-valuenow` as a percentage based on min and max. However, you can set `aria-valuetext` to tell the screen reader to present the value in a different format. It can look something like this:

```
<ol tabindex="0" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="3" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuetext="Step 1 of 3: First Step">
  <li>First Step</li>
  <li>Second Step</li>
  <li>Last Step</li>
</ol>
```

Giving the element `tabindex="0"` will assure that the user tabs to it after each completed step, thus getting the new information.

Be sure to give the non-current sections of content `aria-hidden="true"` to make the screen reader skip them.

### **Update 1**

In the case of `role="tablist"` there are a few different elements that can assist you. In your case, you can use `aria-hidden` and `aria-selected` as your states and control focus with `tabindex`. So let's say the screen reader user is on the first tab, your code can look something like this:

```
<ul role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">
    <a role="tab" href="#section1" id="tab1" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">Tab 1</a>
   </li>
   <li role="presentation">
     <a role="tab" href="#section2" id="tab2" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Tab 2</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<section role="tabpanel" id="section1" aria-labelledby="tab1" aria-hidden="false">
// Tab1 content here
</section>  
<section role="tabpanel" id="section2" aria-labelledby="tab2" aria-hidden="true">
// Tab2 content here  
</section>
```

With this setup your screen reader user is unable to tab to the second tab, and its content is also hidden to the screen reader. You can trigger the appropriate tab when the screen reader user clicks the corresponding button by changing `tabindex`, `aria-hidden`, and `aria-selected`.

If you want to inform the screen reader user of the progress you can simply give the buttons `aria-label`. For example, the button for tab 1 can have: `aria-label="Complete step 1 out of 3"`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Excellent suggestion that I can certainly use elsewhere! But in this particular example I'm using a tablist (see update for more detail). The list needs to have a role="tablist", so I can't also use progressbar

Comment: Thanks for sharing your resource. I updated my answer for `role="tablist"`.

Comment: Using the aria-label to indicate completion state was my initial assumption as well, and that is what I have now implemented. Thanks JazzBrotha.
For others' reference, I ended up using a more recent W3C approach to creating the tablist using buttons rather than list items. In testing, it worked far better with NVDA screen reader and with keyboard accessibility issues:
[W3C Tabs with Manual Activation Example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/tabs/tabs-2/tabs.html)